# How do I leftjoin to table where user_id of one table equal authenticated user

Tags: php, laravel

i have a table name merge_jobs and another table name employer_jobs.

merge_jobs has a column called employer_id which matches with user_id column in employer job

merge_job table also have a column called user_id

So I want to get rows where the user_id in merge_jobs matches the authenticated user where employer_id of the selected rows matches the user_id of the employer_jobs

I tried to use left join but did not work

My code

```
  $jobs = DB::table('job_mergings')
    ->leftJoin('employer_jobs', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('job_mergings.employer_id', '=', 'employer_jobs.user_id');

    })
    ->where('job_mergings.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Could you put the models and columns of tables?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what did not work? The code looks fine, so did you get an error? No results? And if so, is the database correct? Please give some extra info.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's just a mistake in your query and you should correct it like this:

```
->where('job_mergings.employer_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the authenticated user id from the request like this

```
->where('job_mergings.employer_id','=',$request->user()->id)->get();
```